# Google Admin Groups is changing my email address to my associated gmail account

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, contacts-group

I am setting up a Group/mailing list in my Google Admin account, and I am trying to add my email address (personal domain), but Google Admin insists on changing it to my associated gmail account, which I definitely do **not** want. The domain associated with the G Admin account is not my personal domain (a separate non-profit org).

How can I force my desired email address to be added, without the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My email address with the personal domain was listed as an alternate email for my Google account.  I removed that from my G account, and now I can add that email explicitly.